# dynamic - is it reference type, or value type?

Tags: c#, .net

I assume it is of Reference Type as ... you can instantiate stuff like this:

```
dynamic d1 = new SomeClass(); // SomeClass extends from System.Dynamic.DynamicObject
dynamic d2 = new ExpandoObject() ;
d2.x = 100;
d2.y = "120";
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx

Comment: dynamic resolves at runtime

Answer (score 6):

`dynamic` seems to be a reference type, as detailed in MSDN here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types

Answer (score 0):

```
dynamic is Reference Type
```

this is what i get From `C# in Depth`

Let’s
suppose our products aren’t stored in a database, or in XML, or in memory. They’re
accessible via a web service of sorts, but you only have Python code to access it—and
that code uses the dynamic nature of Python to build results without declaring a type
with all the properties you need to access. Instead, it’ll let you ask for any property,
and try to work out what you mean at execution time.

The answer comes in the form of dynamic—a new type,4 which the C# compiler
allows you to use dynamically. If an expression is of type dynamic, you can call methods
on it, access properties, pass it around as a method argument, and so on—and
most of the normal binding process happens at execution time instead of compile
time. You can implicitly convert a value from dynamic to any other type.

```
ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
ScriptScope scope = engine.ExecuteFile("FindProducts.py");
dynamic products = scope.GetVariable("products");
foreach (dynamic product in products)
{
Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", product.ProductName, product.Price);
}
```

Both products and product are declared to be dynamic, so the compiler is happy to
let us iterate over the list of products and print out the properties, even though it
doesn’t know whether it’ll work. If we’d made a typo, using product.Name instead of
product.ProductName, for example, that would only show up at execution time.
This is completely contrary to the rest of C#, which is statically typed. But dynamic
typing only comes into play when expressions with a type of dynamic are involved:
most C# code is likely to remain statically typed throughout.